# How to remove the contents of a <td> in a table dynamically using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want when the user clicks the button with the class name **"removeElement"** the next **"td"** with class **"forRemove"** should have its contents removed.
How can I do it?

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody class="list" id="list">
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button> 
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Removing the TD is the wrong thing to do.  Sure, most browsers will still render it correctly but you're breaking the table really (each TR should have the same number of TDs).  Would you be happy to just remove the contents?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I incorrectly formulated the question. I want to remove content

Comment: No problem - thanks for clarifying.

Comment: There's been some confusion below so I've updated the question to reflect your response to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    <table class="table">
  <tbody class="list" id="list">
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button> 
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
   const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('removeElement');
   for(let i =0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(event) {
    const parent = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
    parent.children[parent.children.length - 1].innerHTML = "";
    }
   }
</script>
```

Is this more or less what you're looking for? To be honest I wouldn't access table elements like this, this is doing a bit much for such simple functionality, for exmaple, on the buttons I would add an indexer at the end of the class name or id, I would use IDs for in this case not only because is faster but also because you'd want quicker access to these elements without the hassle of having to go through so many nodes. i.e.:

```html
    <table class="table">
  <tbody class="list" id="list">
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button id="removeElement-0" class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button> 
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove-0">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button id="removeElement-1" class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove-1">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button id="removeElement-2" class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove-2">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
   const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('removeElement');
   for(let i =0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(event) {
   document.getElementsByClassName("forRemove-"+event.currentTarget.id[event.currentTarget.id.length-1])[0].innerHTML = "";
    }
   }
</script>
```

But Whatever works for you mate.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine. Could you give me a hint how can i remove the next tr with that button? thank you in advance))

Comment: No problemo :), as for your question I think `buttons[i].onclick = function(event) {
  const parent = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
  parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent.nextSibling) }
` 
Should do the trick if im not mistaken

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a great guy.

Comment: Glad I could help, if the answer I gave you for removing the next tr was to your liking, could you up-vote the answer please?, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is here.

```
 $('.removeElement').click(function(e){
         $(this).parent().next().remove();
 });
```

Also, I create the fiddle for you. 
checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xrce4g85/)

Comment: This solution is according to the problem, even working fiddle is there. but the Negative vote is just ridiculous

Answer (score -1):

This will remove the contents of the next TD, with the class `forRemove`

```js
    $(".removeElement").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".forRemove").empty();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody class="list" id="list">
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button> 
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In short, when you click the button it will find the nearest `tr` element by traversing up the DOM tree, and then find the element within that with the class `forRemove`, and then `empty()` it.

Comment: empty() will remove only next td data, will not remove td tag as well, to remove td tag we will use remove() method.

Comment: @SoravGarg Yes, that is correct, and it is what the OP wants.

Comment: I suspect the incorrect downvote is a response to me correctly downvoting other answers (I don't care about it, btw), but I was able to explain my downvote and will remove it if the problems are correctly resolved.  If I've done something actually wrong here then I'd appreciate an explanation so I can fix the errors for the OP's benefit.

Answer (score -1):

This clears the td. It is still there so the table wouldn't brake, but it is emty.

```js
$('.removeElement').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.forRemove').empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody class="list" id="list">
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button> 
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BODY 1</td>
      <td>BODY 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="removeElement">removeNextTd</button>
      </td>
      <td class="forRemove">BODY 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OP does not want to remove the table cell - that would break the table.  They want to empty it.  I've updated the question as per their comment below it.

Answer (score -1):

not exactly what you asked but you can do it like this with jquery

```
$this .parent()
      .parent()
      .remove();
```

since the delete button is within the row you want to delete this should work